# Ui-router nested state with display:none

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a website setup with AngularJS and Ui-router.

Index.html

```
<body>   

    <a href="#">Home Page</a>

<div ui-view></div>

</body>
```

Javascript:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$stateProvider
.state('baba', {
url:"/",
templateUrl: "baba.html"
})
.state('icerik', {
url: "/icerik/:ad",
templateUrl: "icerik.html",
controller: "mmgCtrl",
 })

.state('oku', {
url: "/oku/:serix/:klasor",
templateUrl: "oku.html",
controller: "nbgCtrl"
})

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

})
```

baba.html:

```
<div class="wanTohide> //div that want to hide when ui-sref clicked

    <a ui-sref="oku">State oku</a>
    <a ui-sref="icerik">State icerik</a>

</div>
```

-When any of those ui-sref clicked I want to hide or `display:none` to that div class with `wanTohide`. Of course `ui-sref` clicked it has load its content to `ui-view`.

-I want to functional `Home Page` button.`<a href="">Home Page</a>`

Answer (score 0):

You can `$stateChangeStart` to achieve this. Basically, `$stateChangeStart` is fired whenever a state changes. Code:

**app.js**(where your app is defined) :

```
app.run(run) //assuming app is a variable assigned 'angular.module('AppName', [])'

function run($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
        if(fromState.name == 'oku'|| fromState.name == 'icerik') {
            angular.element('.wantToHide').addClass('hidden');
        }
    }) 
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```